# Show Comment from latest and scroll up to see older comments

Tags: javascript, html, css

i'm new to this but i want to know is there a way to show the last li which is inside div

Ex: i have 20 comments inside a `<div style="height:500px;overflow-y:scroll"></div>`each `<li>`'s height will vary and it crosses height of `<div>`. so we can scroll inside the div to first and last comment

what i want to do is when the page loads i want the last comment to be shown then if user wants he can scroll up to see the older comments.

Answer (score 1):

```
var commentDiv = $('#myDiv');
var distanceToScroll = commentDiv.innerHeight();

commentDiv.scrollTop(distanceToScroll);
```

It may so happen that a comment might be longer than the visible area and the top of the comment might not be visible with the above code.

Then,

```
var lastComment = commentDiv.find('.comments').last();
distanceToScroll -= (lastComment.outerHeight() - 10);
```